# Distribution of suits in a 13 card hand

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Let's say you have 13 cards distributed from a standard deck, find the probability of this distribution of suits: 4, 4, 3, 2, (for instance 4 hearts, 4 clubs, 3 diamonds, 2 spades). My answer was:

$$\frac{ 4*{13\choose 4} * 3*{13\choose 4} * 2*{13\choose 3} * 1 *{13\choose 2} }{52\choose 13}$$

My reasoning being that since there were 4 ways to choose the first suit, 3 ways to to choose the next etc... However the real answer was:

$$\frac{\frac{4!}2 *{13\choose 4} * {13\choose 4} *2 * {13\choose 3} * {13\choose 2}}{52\choose 13}$$

Basically mine divided by 2, what I don't understand why the need to divide by 2. There are 4! ways the suits can be arranged, so why are they arranged in 4!/2 ways in the answer?

Comment: Should the correct answer feature $4!/2!2!$ rather than $4! /2$ ?

Answer (score 2):

You have double-counted. Happens a lot. There is no "first suit" and "second suit." In the $4$ at the beginning of your expression, the choice of $\spadesuit$ was one of the choices counted, and in the subsequent $3$, the choice of $\heartsuit$ is one of the choices counted.

But in the $4$, the choice $\heartsuit$ was counted, and in the subsequent $3$, $\spadesuit$ was one of the choices counted.

But the net result in either case is four each of $\spadesuit$ and $\heartsuit$.

A way to avoid this is to say that the suits we have four in can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. Once we have done that, the actual cards in the higher ranking suit can be chosen in $\binom{13}{4}$ ways, and then the actual cards in the lower ranking suit can be chosen in $\binom{13}{4}$ ways.

Or else we can deliberately double-count, and then divide by 42$.

Answer (score 0):

> Find the probability of this distribution of suits: 4, 4, 3, 2.

Order of suit selection doesn't matter. Distinction come from numbers of cards selected from each suit.

- Select 2 suits from 4.

  - Then select 4 of their 13 cards, each.
- Select 1 suit from the 2 remaining.

  - Then select 3 of its 13 cards.
- Only 1 suit remains to select.

  - So select 2 of its 13 cards.

Multiply the selections together and divide by the total selection space.

$$= \frac{{4\choose 2}{13\choose 4}^2\times{2\choose 1}{13\choose 3}\times{13\choose 2}}{{52\choose 13}}$$

---

Another approach.  First sort the cards into suits, then arrange the suits into groups, or "boxes", labelled '4','3','2' such that 2 suits can be placed in '4' and 1 suit in each of the others.  The count of ways to so arrange the suits into these groups is given by the multinomial coefficient:
$$\frac{4!}{2!1!1!} = {4\choose 2}{2\choose 1}{1\choose 1}$$

Next, select a number of cards from each suit based on their grouping (the numbers on the boxes' labels) :

$$\frac{13!}{4!9!}\times\frac{13!}{4!9!}\times\frac{13!}{3!10!}\times\frac{13!}{2!11!} = {13\choose 4}^2{13\choose 3}{13\choose 2}$$

Put them together, over the total way to select 13 cards.

$$\frac{\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}{13\choose 4}^2{13\choose 3}{13\choose 2}}{52\choose 13} \\ = \frac{13!^5 39!}{2!^2 3! 4! 9!^2 10! 11! 52!}$$

Comment: I see. The distinction is because of the number of cards drawn. Then why does The suit with 3 get assigned 2 ways?

Comment: @WilliamSmith It's because of the number of suits left to assign.  For example, consider the following: You have 4 distinct suits and 3 "boxes" labelled A,B,C, such that 2 suits can go into box A, and 1 each into the others.  The number of possible arrangements are: ${4\choose 2}{2\choose 1}{1\choose 1}$. This is the multinomial coefficient: $\dfrac{4!}{2!1!1!}$.

Comment: I really like the boxes explanation, but why is it 3 boxes and not 4 sorry?

Comment: Because when choosing 2 suits to "pick 4 cards from" we don't care about their order.  It doesn't matter whether you pick "hearts and clubs" or you pick "clubs and hearts".  They're equivalent cases. So we put them in the same 'box'.